# jQuery scroll for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need help with the Jquery scroll function. I want to make the scroll top position to be >= 300 on mobile, tablet, and >= 700 on desktop. Does anyone have any idea how to make it?. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
      $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
      $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid #fff"});
  }
    else {
      $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
      $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.width()` function to get the window width and build an if statement around your function like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
//here we check the viewport width
if($(window).width() < "1024"){
//if the viewport width is less then 1024 scrolltop is 300
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
         $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid    #fff"});
    }
      else {
        $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
    }
}else{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
         $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid    #fff"});
    }
      else {
        $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```